# The number of pairs $(x,y)$ of real numbers satisfying $|\tan(\pi y)|+ \sin^2(\pi x)=0$ and $x^2 + y^2\le2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Here I have a question:

> Find the number of pairs $(x,y)$ of real numbers satisfying the following:
>
> $$|\tan(\pi y)|+ \sin^2(\pi x)=0\quad\textrm{and}\quad x^2 + y^2\le 2$$

The answer is given 9, but i couldn't figure out this. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $|\tan\pi y|\ge0$ and for real $x,\sin^2\pi x\ge0$

We need $\tan\pi y=\sin\pi x=0$

$\tan\pi y=0\implies\pi y=m\pi$

and $\sin\pi x=0\implies\pi x=n\pi$ where $m,n$ are integers

$\implies y=m,x=n$

Answer (score 1):

do you even know about the lattice points in a circle?

The only time when the sum of those functions can be zero is when both functions are zero, since neither function can be negaitve (since both functions are positive semi-definite lol)

The circle $x^2+y^2=2$ only contains $9$ points where $\tan(\pi x)$ and $\sin(\pi y)$=0.

By the way, I have a question: do you know if there is a retract $A$ of the klien bottle $K$ with

\begin{equation*}
 H_1(A) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2? 
\end{equation*}